# Correction of arrow of particle direction

Tags: soft-question, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

I have seen a stamp of Richard Feynman where Feynman hold  the famous Feynman diagram. But is there any problem of the direction of arrow?

[image]

Comment: Is the black arrow your correction?

Comment: actually in the  stamp, the Feynman  diagram didn't have any arrow on the downside I added (black).

Comment: then yes, the arrow you put in should be there

Comment: is there any significance for wearing the hat or the dress?

Comment: fashion? Maybe Dick thought it would be funny?

Comment: I actually wonder if the arrow head was cut during editing.

Comment: I think that is Tuvan garb.  Feynman was interested in Tuvan Throat Singers.  See the book "Tuva or Bust".